# Value of a Drag and Drop with the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a quiz that registers the actions of dragging and dropping. So if you drag the correct 'squares' into the correct 'boxes' and then click the submit button, a result is displayed.

The problem I'm having is: How will the Javascript understand which square is in which box once the submit button is pressed?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<style>
#div1, #div2{float:left; width:50px; height:50px; margin:3px;}
#div3, #div4{float:left; width:56px; height:56px; margin:3px;}
</style>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev){ev.preventDefault();}

function drag(ev){ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);}

function drop(ev){ev.preventDefault();
                  var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
                  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
                 }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<center>

<div style="position:absolute; left: 50px; top: 0px;">
<div id="div1" style="background:#00f" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"     id="drag1"></div>
<div id="div2" style="background:#f00" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag2"></div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; left: 40px; top: 100px;">
<div id="div3" style="border:3px solid #00f" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<div id="div4" style="border:3px solid #f00" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
</div>

<div style="position:absolute; left: 75px; top: 200px;">
<button type="button" class="myBttn" onclick="doSomething()">Submit</button>
</div>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you use the drag and drop event to save the ids of both elements and compare them.

In **[this demo you can see the basics at work](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y5Bsb4SG3KTa0Jmwm5lU?p=preview)**.

```
  <div style="position:absolute; left: 50px; top: 0px;">
    <div id="sourceB" class="b" draggable="true" 
             ondragstart="drag(event)" data-target-id="tb"></div>
    <div id="sourceRed" class="r" draggable="true" 
             ondragstart="drag(event)" data-target-id="tr"></div>
  </div>

  <div style="position:absolute; left: 40px; top: 100px;">
    <div id="tb" class="tb" ondrop="drop(event)" 
                 ondragover="allowDrop(event)" data-match="sourceB"></div>
    <div id="tr" class="tr" ondrop="drop(event)" 
                 ondragover="allowDrop(event)"  data-match="sourceR"></div>
  </div>
```

This is the javascript

```
var droppedElementId;

function drag(ev){
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
  console.log("ev.target.id = ", ev.target.id);
  droppedElementId = ev.target.id;
}

function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    var targetElement = document.getElementById(ev.srcElement.id);
    var dropTarget = targetElement.getAttribute("data-match");
    console.log("ev.srcElement.id =", ev.srcElement.id);
    if(droppedElementId == dropTarget){
        console.log("dropTarget=" + dropTarget);
        console.log("droppedElementId=" + droppedElementId);            
    };      
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

This is just an quick shot and not tested cross browser. It [seems that there are many issues with using drag and drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206828/onmouseover-child-div-problem-and-event-bubbling/2206875#2206875) - it is probably [easier to use a library](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/).

Comment: Thank you, I got your code to work within my application, I appreciate your help.

Comment: I've been able to get this coding to work with Chrome, Opera and IE however Safari isn't allowing the 'drop' to happen (dragging is working) while Firefox isn't even initiating a 'drag'. Is there something I need to add to the code?

Comment: Safari is not my target so i can not help you here. But SO has a few answers regrading safari and drop not working: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Safari+drop+is+not+working